# Android Draw Canvas Bezier Curve and Progress

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

i'm trying to draw something like this in a custom view, it's a progressbar with a complex wave
[image]

The progress is the same Bezier Curve but i have only show a part depending of percent.
[image: this would be the final result]

Actually I managed to draw the Bezier Curve and fill the background Shape thanks to @Blackbelt,

```
        Paint paintBezzier = new Paint() {
            {
                setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
                setAntiAlias(true);
            }
        };

        Paint paintBezzierProgressBase = new Paint() {
            {
                setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
                setAntiAlias(true);
            }
        };


        int xControl1 = 0;
        int yControl1 = 0;

        int xControl2 = 0;
        int yControl2 = 0;


        int x1 = 0;
        int y1 = contentHeight/2;

        int x2 = contentWidth;
        int y2 = contentHeight/2;

        xControl1 = contentWidth/2;
        yControl1 = 0 - 40;

        xControl2 = contentWidth/2;
        yControl2 = contentHeight+40;


        Path backgroundPath = new Path();
        paintBezzier.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        paintBezzier.setStrokeWidth(5);
        backgroundPath.moveTo(x1, y1);
        backgroundPath.cubicTo(xControl1, yControl1, xControl2, yControl2, x2, y2);
        backgroundPath.lineTo(x2, y2);
        backgroundPath.lineTo(contentWidth, contentHeight);
        backgroundPath.lineTo(x1, contentHeight);
        backgroundPath.lineTo(x1, y1);
        backgroundPath.close();

        //TODO calculate progress

        Path pathProgress = new Path();
        paintBezzierProgressBase.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F1AD3D"));
        paintBezzierProgressBase.setStrokeWidth(7);
        pathProgress.moveTo(x1, y1);
        pathProgress.cubicTo(xControl1, yControl1, xControl2, yControl2, x2, y2);


        canvas.drawPath(backgroundPath, paintBezzier);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paintBezzierProgressBase);
```

Any idea how can i calculate the percent and show only a part of curve?
this is the image goal.

Thanks in advanced
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it using ClippingPath

```
  canvas.clipRect(rectangle, Region.Op.REPLACE);
  canvas.drawPath(pathProgress, paintBezzierProgressBase);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `FILL_AND_STROKE` as style for your `paintBezzier` instead of `STROKE`. Or probably you want also to close the area around you want to draw the with, and then use one of the fill style of path

Comment: i tried it without luck http://postimg.org/image/6w0fzxjlz/ and yes, i don't know how to close the bottom area

Comment: is that fill and stroke?

Comment: yes,  Paint paintBezzier = new Paint() {
            {
                setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
                setAntiAlias(true);
            }
        };
i think it's happening because y don't have it closed in bottom side. how can i continue drawing the same path? is it possible?

Comment: I was quit sure, but it was worth a try. Try to draw some line to complete the frame of your path, and call close on the path instance, like I do in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119936/porterduff-and-path). In the end I was able to fill the are of the path

Comment: Blackbelt, thank you for your post. I solved to fill the shape, but i'm going to edit the question.